# ActiveAdmin -- how to reference current object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

How can you reference the instance of the object you are currently viewing?

The following **WORKS**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Example do

  sidebar "test" do
    @name = example.name
  end

end
```

The following **DOESN'T Work**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Example do

  member_action :some_stuff, :method => :put do
    @name = example.name
  end

end
```

How can I reference the object in the member_action?

Or will I have to create another instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the active admin documentation is out of date or completely nonexistent.  You will likely have to read the source and hope somebody commented functions if you want the nitty-gritty on how to use it.

The [`member_action` function documentation](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb) is as follows:

```
# Member Actions give you the functionality of defining both the
# action and the route directly from your ActiveAdmin registration
# block.
#
# For example:
#
#   ActiveAdmin.register Post do
#     member_action :comments do
#       @post = Post.find(params[:id]
#       @comments = @post.comments
#     end
#   end
#
# Will create a new controller action comments and will hook it up to
# the named route (comments_admin_post_path) /admin/posts/:id/comments
#
# You can treat everything within the block as a standard Rails controller
# action.
#
```

This makes it look like they expect you to perform your own object lookup in custom actions - `Post.find(params[:id])`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'resource' object.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Example do

  member_action :some_stuff, :method => :put do
    @name = resource.name
  end

end
```